# How can I change charset in SASS (SCSS)

Tags: css, sass

When working on web projects I'm using css preprocessor SASS with SCSS syntax. In the comments, I like to write what the following code does, I write comments in my language (in czech). Unfortunately, when you compile it throws me the error coding. I'm using for compilation app Koala.

**Error msg by compilation:**

```
 Error: Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC5" on line 7 
 of /Users/martinjinda/Documents/www/_welcome_screen/local/sass/main.scss 
 Use --trace for backtrace.
```

**SCSS code:**

```
 // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Import všech zdrojových souborů a následná kompilace do /css/main.css

 @import 'reset.scss';
 @import 'typo.scss';
 @import 'mixins.scss';
 @import 'layout.scss';
 @import 'content.scss';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS prepends incorrect @charset rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363506/sass-prepends-incorrect-charset-rule)

Comment: It worked, yes, thx. But I this option need set globaly for all my files and sub-files. I try added `Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"` but isn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `@charset "UTF-8";` on the beginning of file, before any spaces, comments.

Comment: Well, you can always try writing your comments in english, just in case some other developer working on the code did not know Czech :)

Answer (score 0):

Since [LibSass is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated), you must use [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) instead. With it, you don't need to specify the [input encoding](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/parsing#input-encoding) because default (and [only supported until now](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/568)) is "UTF-8".
I tried you're Sass code with Dart Sass and no error is returned!