# Wrong bullet transpilling in SCSS in PhpStorm

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm using PhpStorm's File Watcher to transpill SCSS into CSS. In my SCSS I have:

```
li {               
       &:before {
           content: "•";
           font-size: 85%;
           padding-right: 5px;
       }
}
```

but it transpiles to:

```
li:before {
       content: "ÔÇó";
       font-size: 85%;
       padding-right: 5px;
}
```

How can I configure this to transpile properly?

(watcher: `C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\scss.bat`)

Comment: try adding `@charset` declaration to your scss - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363506/sass-prepends-incorrect-charset-rule. Actually, scss compiler should add it automatically if there are non -ASCII chars in original SCSS... Note: this is not a problem with PHPStorm, it's a problem of SCSS compiler.

Comment: thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found it:
add to first line of your scss:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

voila!